# How to override toString of Object whose class defintion is not accessible?

Tags: java, selenium, overriding, tostring

Pardon me if Subject of Question is confusing[Please edit Subject].

I have difficulty in understanding/implementing this very obvious usecase. I am sure, there is definetly an easy solution which I am not able to think of.

**My code:**

```
Response response = driver.execute("findElement", "{using=xpath, value=//*[@id='myID']}");

System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Now this `System.out.println` prints:

`(Response: SessionID: ffcebc9226c9671e7f6725a3b1f5a96c, Status: 0, Value: [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@c6bdd2e4 -> unknown locator])`

As, it is not printing complete Object correctly for known reasons. Hence,
I want to @Override `toString` method of `Response` class.

Now my difficulty is, if I `extends` `Response` class as say `CommandResponse` and then use with typecast of `CommandResponse` following:

```
CommandResponse response = (CommandResponse) driver.execute("findElement", "{using=xpath, value=//*[@id='myID']}");
```

I get error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response
>   cannot be cast to src.main.CommandResponse

So, my question is, how I can override correctly ?

Please advice.

Comment: What is the reason behind overriding this? Why are you using driver.execute directly?

Comment: @TarunLalwani: I am actually recording Command, CommandParam, CommandResponse in DB, and then trying to replay it using them. This is as per my usecase requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suitable solution would be to *inject* the Selenium `Response` object into your wrapper object by means of constructor parametrization.

The constructor would then simply assign an own `Response` field with the object you pass.

Something like:

```
CommandResponse response = new CommandResponse(driver.execute(...));
```

...

```
public CommandResponse(Response arg) {
    this.response = arg;
}
```

This way, you are using a wrapper object *and* composition.

Your `CommandResponse` object would override the `toString` method and build the `String` representation by picking whatever fields you need from the `Response` object.